# JList DefaultListModel ListSelectionListener

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have 2 DefaultListModels inside a JSplitPane.  The left side of the JSplitPane
has RssChannel titles.  When a RssChannel title is selected, the RssItem titles 
are supposed to show up on the right side of the JSplitPane.

The initial time RssChannel title is selected the correct RssItem titles appear.
But when I go back and forth between the RssChannel titles, the correct RssItem titles 
don't fire.

How can I fix my Listener so that the correct RssItem titles are always fired from their respective RssChannel?

Thanks for any suggestions

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;


public class GuiDriver extends JFrame{
    JList channelTitleList, itemTitleList;
    DefaultListModel cModel, iModel;
    List<RssReader> feedList = new ArrayList<RssReader>();
    int nextFeed=0;

    public GuiDriver(){
    }

    public void addFeed(RssReader feed){
       feedList.add(feed);
    }


    public JToolBar createToolBar(){
       JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();
       Action newToolBarButton = new AddAction("New");
       Action deleteToolBarButton = new RemoveAction("Delete");
       Action clearToolBarButton = new ClearAction("Clear");

       bar.add(newToolBarButton);  
       bar.add(deleteToolBarButton);
       bar.add(clearToolBarButton);

       bar.setFloatable(false);      
       return bar;
    }


    public JSplitPane createJSplitPane(){
       JSplitPane hSplitPane  = new JSpli tPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,createChannelJScrollPane(), createItemJScrollPane());
       hSplitPane.setDividerLocation(500);
       return hSplitPane;
   }


   public JScrollPane createChannelJScrollPane(){            
      cModel = new DefaultListModel(); 
      channelTitleList = new JList(cModel);
      JScrollPane channelJScrollPane = new JScrollPane(channelTitleList);
      channelTitleList.setVisibleRowCount(20);
      channelTitleList.getSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ChannelListListener());      

      return channelJScrollPane;     
   }


   public JScrollPane createItemJScrollPane(){
      iModel = new DefaultListModel();
      itemTitleList = new JList(iModel);
      JScrollPane itemJScrollPane = new JScrollPane(itemTitleList);

      return itemJScrollPane;
   }   


   public class AddAction extends AbstractAction{
      public AddAction(String name){
         super(name);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         System.out.println(getValue(Action.NAME)+" selected.");
         JOptionPane message = new JOptionPane();
         String firstInput = message.showInputDialog(null, "Enter URL");
         try{
            DumpStockPage.readXml(firstInput);
            File f = new File("RSSFeed.xml");
            addFeed(new RssReader(f));

            cModel.addElement(feedList.get(nextFeed).rssChannel.getTitle());
            nextFeed++;
            iModel.clear();
         }
         catch (IOException ee){
            System.err.println(ee);
         }
      }
   }


   public class RemoveAction extends AbstractAction{
      public RemoveAction(String name){
         super(name);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         cModel.removeElement(channelTitleList.getSelectedValue());
         feedList.remove(e);
         iModel.clear();
      } 
   }

   public class ClearAction extends AbstractAction{
      public ClearAction(String name){
         super(name);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         iModel.clear();
      } 
   }


   private class ChannelListListener implements ListSelectionListener {
      public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e) {        
         boolean adjust = e.getValueIsAdjusting();
         if (!adjust) {
            int i = e.getLastIndex();
            for (int j=0; j<feedList.get(i).rssChannel.getItems().size(); j++)
               iModel.addElement(feedList.get(i).rssChannel.items.get(j).getTitle());
         }
      }
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
            GuiDriver frame = new GuiDriver(); 

            frame.setTitle("RSS Reader");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            frame.add(frame.createJSplitPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(frame.createToolBar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(800,400);
         }   
      });  
   }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  As for suggestions, I suggest you ask a question.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the implementation of RssReader, but your `ChannelListListener` keeps adding data to your item list. What you want is a list of titles for the selected item from `channelTitleList`. Get the selected index using `getSelectedIndex()` of `JList`. Next, build the content of `itemTitleList`, for instance as a list of strings, based on the selected feed. Here's an example for the `ChannelListListener` to get you started:

```
public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e) {        
     boolean adjust = e.getValueIsAdjusting();
     if (!adjust) {
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = channelTitleList.getSelectedIndex(); //the index of the selected item in the left list

        //Change RssFeed to the appropriate class for these 'items'
        for(RssFeed feed: feedList.get(i).rssChannel.items) {
            titles.add(feed.getTitle());  //build a list of titles, to be shown in the right list
        }

        itemTitleList.setListData(titles.toArray()); //change the content of the right list
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add an RssChannel and click on it, the correct RssItem titles appear.  But if I add multiple RssChannels and then try clicking on them from the bottom of the list going up, only the first selection correctly appears.  The next selection will then have RssChannel title's for the item previously clicked on and so on.

Comment: It seems like you're not building the content of the items the way you want it. I changed my answer with a way to get the list of titles for the selected feed.